# Hover em seletor :before

Tags: css, css3, css-hover

Me deparei em uma situação, até sei como contornar, fazendo de outra forma, mas gostaria de saber, se é possível utilizar :hover em um elemento :before, tenho a seguinte estrutura:

```
<a href="" class="call-box call-info-city block">
  Informações da cidade
</a>
<a href="" class="call-box call-benefits block">
  Benefícios Fiscais
</a>
```

Onde, o elemento **call-box**, tem um seletor :before, na seguinte forma:

```
.call-box {
    float: left;
    font-family: 'LatoBold', arial, sans-serif;
    color: #909090;
    height: 52px;
    width: 150px;
    padding: 10px 0 0 62px;
    line-height: 16px;
    position: relative;
}
.call-box:before {
    position: absolute;
    content: '';
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    border: 2px solid #00BF8B;
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
       -moz-border-radius: 50%;
            border-radius: 50%;
}
```

No hover do elemento call-box, gostaria de modificar o seletor :before, é possível?

Answer (score 7):

Pfss, resolvido.

```
.call-box:hover:before {
  background-color: #00BF8B;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Sim, é possível da seguinte maneira: http://jsfiddle.net/jhwmxfrz/

```
.call-box:hover:before {
    background-color: #00BF8B;
}
```